# How to storage link in host?

Tags: php, laravel

I upload my project in the host. I uploaded an image, and the image save in database. And the image did not show well, but it show in my localhost as well.

web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/link', function(){
    return Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

Controller

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $path = $user->image ?? null;
    if ($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $nane = time();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $nane . '.' . $extension;
        $path = $file->storeAs('images/users', $fileName, 'public');
    }
    $user->image = $path;
}
```

The image save in database.

The image uploaded in storage/app/public/images/users folder.

The image did not uploaded public/images/users.

Comment: Do you have the symbolic link from storage/app/public to public/storage? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Yes, I runned `php artisan storage:link` in my localhost, then i uploaded

Comment: You should run `php artisan storage:link` on the server again

Comment: How? Route::get('/link', function(){
    return Artisan::call('storage:link');
});

Comment: Don't you have terminal access on the server? You should run it via terminal. If you don't have terminal access then you can try via a route as you have in above comment

Comment: You need a symbolic link. If you will use artisan or not is up to you, as long as you have the symbolic link you're  good to go

Comment: How to run it via terminal?

Comment: The same way you must have done it in your local machine - open a terminal cd your-project then run php artisan storage:link

Comment: Look at my post. I written in web.php `return Artisan::call('storage:link');`

Comment: Yeah its ok as @FelippeDuarte has mentioned symbolic link is required whether you create via terminal or programatically via a route doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an access to server with ssh? If not you can write like this in your route :

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

It will generate the symlink to your public_html, sorry for my bad english